# How does surface area relate to the Seebeck Equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics

I know that the equation is
$$V = (S_B-S_A)(T_2-T_1),$$ but surely this output voltage must be proportional to the surface area (and probably thickness) of the Peltier device. What is the formula that yields voltage for a given Peltier device based on materials, $\Delta T$ and surface area?

Comment: As discussed in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seebeck_coefficient), for example, the voltage depends on the temperature and the amount of entropy transferred by charge carriers in the materials, a material property. (The Seebeck effect arises because heat transfer is entropy transfer and because charge carriers carry entropy as well; thus, a temperature difference tends to drive charge flow.) Scaling up the area scales up the available current, not the voltage. Scaling up the thickness reduces the temperature gradient.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage does in fact surprisingly not depend on surface area. You can compare it to a capacitor with larger or smaller plates - if you attach the same battery then the stored charge and thus the achieved voltage will be the same regardless (that is, the battery voltage).

In a battery the reason is that the electrochemical reactions that take place produce a specific voltage each. Voltage does not accumulate.

A thermoelectric material is typically a semiconductor. The battery's electrochemical reactions can be compared to the electron "jumps" in this semiconductor. They need to "jump" across the band gap and then we call them excited and "free" to roam about. This is how a temperature gradient causes a Seebech module to suddenly produce electric current.

It is the band gab size that determines the voltage you achieve. Regardless of how many electrons you have excited. They only determine how much current (charge per second) that you can produce from this setup, but not how large their "electronic pressure" - the voltage - can be.